# Azure DevOps Yaml Pipline gitversion/execute failing ObjectHandle.op_Implicit(ObjectHandle handle) in /_/LibGit2Sharp/Core/Handles/Objects.cs:line 509

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, gitversion

Getting error when run task gitversion/execute on azure devops yaml pipeline
 `An unexpected error occurred: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. at LibGit2Sharp.Core.Handles.ObjectHandle.op_Implicit(ObjectHandle handle) in /_/LibGit2Sharp/Core/Handles/Objects.cs:line 509 at LibGit2Sharp.Core.Proxy.git_commit_author(ObjectHandle obj) in /_/LibGit2Sharp/Core/Proxy.cs:line 289 at`
comming from `##[debug]fetchDepth=1`
with not option to setup in yaml, as this was change as default value for Microsoft.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Option to setup fetch is hidden in ADO under pipeline Edit button -> Triggers -> [image]

Or use

```
variables:
  Agent.Source.Git.ShallowFetchDepth: 0
```

or if the repository is also checkout as dedicated task

```
steps:
  - checkout: self
    fetchDepth: 0
    clean: true
```

Comment: Awesome!  Had a build with this error, and sure, it was exactly what you said here!   But, the ShallowFetchDepth has to be greater than 1 in order to be able to find a version starting point, or turned completely off.

Answer (score 6):

This happens with pipelines created after Sept. 2022. If you're using a YAML pipeline, replace:

```
- checkout: self
  persistCredentials: true
```

with:

```
- checkout: self
  fetchDepth: 0
  persistCredentials: true
```

The `-checkout` task performs a shallow fetch in pipelines created after Septembre 2022. Since gitversion needs the full commit history to find tags, it tries and crashes. Specifying `fetchDepth: 0` disable shallow fetch.

References: [Gitversion](https://github.com/GitTools/GitVersion/issues/2690), [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema/steps-checkout?view=azure-pipelines#shallow-fetch).